# Please tell me which one of these sentences is correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I want to request people to update my contact number.
Here's the message I wrote:

> Hey! I am changing my WhatsApp to a new number.  Here it is: XXXXXXX.

Should I then add

> Please update your contact information **for me.**

or

> Please update your contact information **of me.**

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> Please update your contact information for me.

It is the information they use for contacting you, not details they use of contacting you.

Actually, if I could change it I would say:

> Please update the relevant contact information

They might not need to update all the information. For example if they have your address or another phone number and it stays the same they don't need to update it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is anything it's ***for*** me. But it is not a common construction in this context; I have found just one example of it in published literature on google books:

*I specifically authorize the release of information pertaining to Slate Canyon's detention hearing paperwork on CHILD, including **contact information for me** and CHILD.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=yMVYAAAAYAAJ&q=%22contact+information+for+me%22&dq=%22contact+information+for+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib76ys0_zfAhWHZd8KHUeaCysQ6AEINTAC)

I did find one example of ***of*** me [(here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=mthQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22contact+information+of+me%22&dq=%22contact+information+of+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1-vC11PzfAhWmFbkGHcHxCRAQ6AEIKjAA), but it seems that was not written by a native speaker.

What makes the *for me* sentence a bit more difficult to process than it should be is this: the *for me* construction can also be used in the sense of *on my behalf*. Here's an [an example](https://books.google.com/books?id=pb3SAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA141&dq=%22contact%20information%20for%20me%22&pg=PA141#v=onepage&q=%22contact%20information%20for%20me%22&f=false): *Can you look up her contact information **for me**?*

Thus, although *for me* is correct, it would be much better to rephrase the statement in any of the ways suggested by the other answers here. These include:

*Please update the contact information you have for me.*<sup>1</sup> (I think this is closest to your original one.)
*Please update my contact details in your contacts list.*<sup>1</sup>
*Please update the relevant contact information.*<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>Suggested by Dissabled Dave.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>Suggested by D Manokhin.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go for "Please update the contact information you have for me." or "Please update my contact details in your contacts list." that said, if you specifically want to use one of the two options you have listed, I would use the first as it is the information they use **for** contacting you, not details they use **of** contacting you.